# Are there any sort of incompatibilities between the Optimization Library of Modelica and the TIL commercial library?

Tags: optimization, modelica, incompatibility

I suspect that the two libraries cannot work well together. Do you know something about it?

More specifically, I'm working on a transcritical CO2 heat pump and I want to find the optimal high pressure that maximizes the COP. The thing is that as soon as I put the signal criteria, the overall model won't translate anymore, giving me errors related to a TIL component (an heat exchanger).
Everything works fine otherwise.

I know that TLK Energy has an optimization tool called Optimization Suite but I wanted to try the Modelica Optimization Library before asking them about their software.

EDIT: this is the error I get when translating the model. This happens only when I put the signal criteria block in the model, just as it can be seen in one of the example (controllerdDesign_F14). Perhaps am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the Optimization library created by the DLR?

Comment: Yes, I am. That's the library I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with TIL libraries, but there should not be any fundamental incompatibility. Can you add the error message to your question?

Answer (score 2):

That `criteria`-block uses `absMax` and `overshoot` blocks that both require that the input signal can be differentiated; and the TIL-library does not allow differentiation of the model.

You could (likely) work around this issue by using a first-order filter between your model and the `criteria`-block; alternatively using a different `criteria`-block